# Generating complex types with all properties equivalent

Tags: autofixture

Does *AutoFixture* have a facility to create multiple instances of a given type with all the same data? My classes are not serializable and I need two models which are not reference equivalent, but instead have matching properties.

```
public class Foo
{
    // Many more properties and similar models needing the same semantics.
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var a = fixture.Create<Foo>();
var b = fixture.Create<Foo>();

Assert.False(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
Assert.Equal(a.Name, b.Name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that AutoFixture can do this, but [Albedo](https://github.com/AlbedoOrg/Albedo) can. While this is only proof-of-concept code, it should illustrate the general idea, I hope.

Create a new class, deriving from `ReflectionVisitor<T>`:

```
public class PropertyCopyVisitor<T> : ReflectionVisitor<T>
{
    private readonly T source;
    private readonly T destination;

    public PropertyCopyVisitor(T source, T destination)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public override IReflectionVisitor<T> Visit(
        PropertyInfoElement propertyInfoElement)
    {
        var pi = propertyInfoElement.PropertyInfo;
        pi.SetValue(this.destination, pi.GetValue(this.source));
        return this;
    }

    public override T Value
    {
        get { return this.destination; }
    }
}
```

The pivotal part of the implementation is the `Visit` overload where it uses Reflection to copy each property from `source` to `destination` object.

Since this implementation mutates `destination`, the `Value` property is never used, but it has to be there because it's `abstract` in `ReflectionVisitor<T>`...

You can now write your test as:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var a = fixture.Create<Foo>();
var b = fixture.Create<Foo>(); // Or just create a new, empty Foo...
// This copies all properties from a to b:
new TypeElement(typeof(Foo)).Accept(new PropertyCopyVisitor<Foo>(a, b));

Assert.False(ReferenceEquals(a, b));
Assert.Equal(a.Name, b.Name);
```

Here, I still used `fixture` to create `b`, but you don't have to do that, because all properties are going to be overwritten anyway. If `Foo` has a parameterless constructor, you could instead simply use `new Foo()`; it'd make no difference.

This proof-of-concept explicitly only copies properties. If you need to copy fields as well, you'll have to override the appropriate `Visit` method as well. Furthermore, if the objects in question take constructor arguments, you'll need to deal with those explicitly as well.

If you find it tedious to write `new TypeElement(typeof(Foo)).Accept(new PropertyCopyVisitor<Foo>(a, b));`, I'm sure you can figure out a way to write a helper method around it.

As an additional note, `PropertyCopyVisitor` doesn't *have* to be generic, because it doesn't actually use the `T` type argument for anything. I just like the type safety that this gives the constructor...