# AutoFixture: How to set (nested) properties manually based on a pattern

Tags: c#, tdd, system.reflection, autofixture

I have the following nested classes, that are coming from XSD files generated via xsd.exe.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public AnotherClass[] PropertyOne; 

    public DateTime PropertyTwo; 

    public bool PropertyTwoSpecified
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public DateTime AnotherPropertyOne

    public bool AnotherPropertyOneSpecified

    public int AnotherPropertyTwo

    public bool AnotherPropertyTwoSpecified
}
```

Now I would like to use AutoFixture to generate instances with synthetic data.

```
var fixture = new Fixture(); 
fixture.Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());

var myClassFake = fixture.Create<MyClass>();
```

I know I can use `.with` to set single properties, but how can I set properties based on a specific pattern? Especially when this properties are nested in arrays?

I basically have to ensure that all properties ending with `*Specified` are getting set to `true`. Including the once nested into `PropertyOne`

Do I have to use my one reflection based method, e.g. an extension method (e.g. `myClassFake.EnableAllProperties()`) or is there an AutoFixture-way to achieve my goal?

---

**Edit**

I know I can use `fixture.Register<bool>(() => true);` to set all my bools to true. This solves my very specific problem, but still feels clumsy and not generally applicable. Still looking for the precise way to solve this.

Comment: That dupe hammer of mine bothers me a bit; I'd much rather like to *vote* to close this as a duplicate. If the other post doesn't answer your question, though, please let me know, and I'll reopen this question again.

Comment: Unfortunately the linked post does not answer my question. I am trying to set a specific set of properties (based on a pattern) to a specific value. E.g. setting all properties ending with `*Specified` to `true` or setting all (nested) properties which name is `OID` to a specific value/generation algorithm. I hope its somehow clear what I am trying to achieve. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `ReflectionVisitor` used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167338/126014 ought to be useful for that task as well, but I don't mind reopening the question...

Comment: Thx Mark. I ended up creating two implementations of `ISpecimenbuilder`. Although I am not sure if I am using the `RangedNumberRequest` the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating two implementations of `ISpecimenBuilder` that work perfectly for my situation.

This one sets all boolean properties ending on *Specified to true without affecting other boolean properties.

```
public class SpecifiedBoolSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;

        if (pi == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(bool) || !pi.Name.EndsWith("Specified"))
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This one sets a specific property to a range of random values:

```
public class OidSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public int Min { get; set; }

    public int Max { get; set; }

    public OidSpecimenBuilder(int min, int max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max; 
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;

        if (pi == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(long) || pi.Name != "OID")
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        return context.Resolve(new RangedNumberRequest(typeof(long), Min, Max));
    }
}
```